# How do I setX and setY in percentage?

Tags: android, image, position

I want to position an image dynamically.

setX and setY works fine, but in pixels. 
I want my app to be escalable to every device's screen.
Furthermore, I want it to work in landscape mode.

What's the proper method?

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp) The first answer is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

setX and setY aren't the proper way to position images in Android.

You have to use either LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to have a design supported on any orientations and any devices.

Layouts and ImageViews can be created and added dynamically.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayout)
TextView txt1 = new TextView(MyClass.this);
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);
```

*Thanks the source code author : Deepak*

You only have to change TextView for ImageView.

Comment: But this is for a static case, my image moves on every onLocationChange iteration. I can put image inside a Layout but then I have to move it with something like setX.

Comment: Ok, can you tell a bit more about your goal ? I don't really understand. What your app is doing ?

Comment: I have a bar with a ball inside. Every time location changes, it calculates position ball should have inside that bar. The ball is a Imageview, and the bar a LinearLayout.

Comment: It is working fine for my screen giving a value in pixels to ImageView setX, but I installed the app in another device and realized it doesn't fit.