# pixels to dp convertor based on ppi

Tags: android, ppi

I am converting px to dp for given graphics. Going through docs I noticed that 1dp = 3px for 480ppi screen(xxhdpi).

I am testing it on Redmi Note3 which has approx 403 ppi.

I have been provided margins in pixels by my designer. Should I convert those into pixels to by using 1:3 ratio or it should be different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting pixels to dp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
 * This method converts dp unit to equivalent pixels, depending on device density. 
 * 
 * @param dp A value in dp (density independent pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into pixels
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent px equivalent to dp depending on device density
 */
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return px;
}

/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
```

for more information look into this SOF post [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)