# How do I dynamically change the color of a drawable <shape>? (Android)

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-color

Each button represents something clickable, which has a color stored in the database that a user can configure. The background of the button is the `<shape>` that follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFF"
            android:centerColor="#FFF"
            android:endColor="#666"
            android:angle="315" />
  <padding android:bottom="2dp"
           android:left="2dp"
           android:right="2dp"
           android:top="2dp" />
</shape>
```

I'd like to get at the `<gradient>` element — specifically the `startColor` `centerColor` and `endColor` attributes. I can do this:

```
button.getBackground().setTint(theColor);
```

But that seems to wipe out the stroke and gradient.

Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Comment: have you tried this way `((GradientDrawable)button.getBackground()).setColor(theColor);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below snippet, give it a try

[image: Have a look at this screenshot]

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white), ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red_500), ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue_500)});
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setStroke(1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
    gd.setCornerRadius(5f);
    gd.setBounds(2, 2, 2, 2);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_analytics).setBackground(gd);
```

Comment: So basically just reconstructing the XML. In this case I should do away with the XML entirely rather than duplicate the logic. But this approach works, so I'll probably go with it. A necessary change though is to multiply the pixel values by the density. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp Thank you!

Comment: Yeah exactly, you don't need to use xml anymore

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)button.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers have pointed out, it is a `GradientDrawable` which, it turns out, has a fancy [setColors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColors(int[])) method, allowing direct access to those three xml attributes in order. But it must be preceded by a call to [mutate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#mutate()) like so:

```
GradientDrawable gd = ((GradientDrawable) button.getBackground());
gd.mutate();
gd.setColors(new int[]{dynamicColor,
   ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button),
   ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.button_shade)});
```

@Bhavnik got me halfway there, so thanks.