# Android Studio XML getMeasuredWidth ()

Tags: android, xml, pixel

The getMeasuredWidth() method measures the width in pixels, is there a similar method that measures the width in dp?

Comment: What for? Everything is drawn in pixels. DP is only there to help you with your layouts

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp

Comment: No there is no method to get width in dp. But you can use another method to convert pixels to dp.

Answer (score 0):

**No,** there is no method to get view `width` in `dp`. But you can use below method to convert `Pixels` to `DP`.

```
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return dp;
}
```

For more clarification see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp).