# Resize drawable image in TextView android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview, android-drawable

Wonder how to resize an image inside a `TextView` xml in a `LinearLayout`. I read some solution using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method, but cannot get it right.

Here is the image:

[image]

I want to reduce the size of the logo.

Here is my TextView code:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/android_logo"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/android_logo"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/heading"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Try  :**

```
 android:scaleX="0.7"
 android:scaleY="0.7"
```

**OR**

Wrap your resource in a drawable that defines your desired size similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
      android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:height="@dimen/icon_size"
      />

</layer-list >
```

then use it in drawable left.

Comment: The 2nd suggestion works with TextView with the image. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @PattyPutty Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Note "width" and "height" item attributes don't work in Android versions older than 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

there is only one solution take image view for the image and resize image but text display image right side . you used below code and i hope your issue solved..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_person" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="heading"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic solution:

You can use `drawable.setBounds` but it requires pixels rather than dp as parameters.

how to convert: [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

code:

```java
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_your_drawable);
        int size = dp2px(this, dpSize);
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
        }

        textView.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, drawable, drawable, drawable); // should be (drawable, null, null, null) for you
```