# How to place a Button properly over an ImageView?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, margin

My application has a button as well as an `ImageView` (of a piano keyboard) arranged in a `FrameView`. When a key on the piano keyboard is clicked, the button gets moved there by setting it's topMargin and leftMargin via the following:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)noteButton.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(leftMargin,topMargin,0,0);
```

The actual margin is calculated differently depending on the key, but generally uses the Width and Height aquired via `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` within `onWindowFocusChanged()`. The calculation for the first black key, C# or Db, looks like the following:

```
leftMargin = (int) (pianoImageViewWidth/7 - buttonSize/2);
```

Since the piano graphic is 7 keys wide and the black key is between the first and second key (see image).

My problem now is the actual margins are not centered; they're actually somewhat far off, like in the following example.

[image: Example]

It is generally worse towards the left side of the keyboard. On smaller dp devices, it's so far to the left it's out of the bounds of the black key. I absolutely cannot figure out what is going wrong there, I hope somebody here can help me adjust this.

Additionally, here is the code to get the width and height:

```
    int pianoImageWidth  = imagePiano.getWidth();
    int pianoImageHeight = imagePiano.getHeight();
    int buttonSize = noteButton.getWidth();
```

And the XML of the actual piano and button:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/piano_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_button"

        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="0dp"

        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/note"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piano_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/piano" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: margins you're setting in `px` or recalculating it into `dp` values?

Comment: @Dumbo I'm not doing any conversions. I should be getting it in px with getWidth() and setting it in px with params.setMargins()

Comment: The different devices have different amount of pixels so you should use `dp` because it is more adaptive. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/5272951

Comment: @Dumbo I am calculating this during runtime with the actual amount of pixels on the screen. You can't set margins in dp during runtime.

Comment: You can do it. If I not mistaken you should use: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;` to get density. And multiply the value with the `leftMargin` and `topMargin` before setting them as margin values.

Comment: @Dumbo I tried doing this, but the Margin becomes way bigger. I think the conversion into dp is really not needed here, since I've only done calculations with the picture size on the screen in pixels and ratios thereof.

Comment: Maybe, I don't know why it could be wrong. Because whenever I creating any `View` programmatically I am always converting `px` into `dp` and thats works fine for me all the time and the created View is the same in all different devices

Comment: @Dumbo But if you check the Documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth() , you can see that getWidth() returns the width in pixels, not dp. And params.setMargins() also takes the margins in px, not dp.

Comment: As I said I am offering you to get `px` from `getWidth()`, convert it to `dp` value and set it to `setMargin()`. And what the android developer page says is not always the best practice

Comment: @Dumbo Ah, I got you now. Sadly using that approach, the margins end up way too big again, since the LayoutParams.setMargins() takes pixel value margins, not dpi.

Comment: Try to use these methods for converting `px` to `dp`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/5272951

Comment: @Dumbo This, too, does not work. Can you tell me why I want to convert into dpi if I get the image size in Pixels and the Margins programmatically gets set in Pixels?

Answer (score 0):

getHeight() and getWidth() is going wrong in your case i think.
Can you please show more code of how you are taking getHeight() and getWidth() ?

the correct way to get width and height is :

```
view.getLayoutParams().height
view.getLayoutParams().width
```

Comment: I am doing the following
`int pianoImageWidth  = imagePiano.getWidth();
int pianoImageHeight = imagePiano.getHeight();`

Using getLayoutParams().height only gives me the constant for "Wrap Content", since this is what I used. It doesn't return actual sizes.

Comment: so for your piano image you should to set match parent . Can you please provide the xml design?

Comment: The correct way to get width and height is `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`, because this is the value of pixels of (top minus bottom) and (right minus left). `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` is the distance from edge to the `View`.

Comment: I added the XML as well as the calls to retrieve the image size to the Post.

Comment: May be you are missing the spacing around the white keys in pianoImageViewWidth/7