# Conversion of dp to px and px to dp. Conceptual misunderstanding.

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a bit confused regarding the conversion of dp to px and px to dp. The formula goes this way

> px = dp*(dpi/160)

Let's consider two screens A & B of densities of 160 dpi and 320 dpi respectively. This itself means that in the same area B has more number of pixels than A which means the pixel size of 160dpi screen should be larger for the same screen size and should be equal to the physical size of 2 pixels of 320dpi screen. But, putting in the formula for B this gives that 1 pixel for B is equivalent to the physical size of 2 density independent pixels or 2 pixels of 160dpi screen.  What am I missing here?

Comment: 1 dp on A = 1*(160/160) = 1px. 1dp on B = 1*(320/160) = 2px. So each dp on A screen will take 1 pixel, while 1 dp on B screen will take 2 pixels. While both them will take same size in milimeters on both screens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

Comment: Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the scaling system with this example. Pretend you have a bitmap you want to display **48dp x 48dp** big on each screen (independently from density).
We have:

- mDPI, 160dpi screen (ratio **1x**) --> bitmap: **48x48 px** (old devices)
- hDPI, 240dpi screen (ratio **1.5x**) --> bitmap: **72x72 px (48 x 1.5)**
- xhDPI, 320dpi screen (ratio **2x**) --> bitmap: **96x96 px (48 x 2)**
- xxhDPI, 480dpi screen (ratio **3x**) --> bitmap: **144x144 px (48 x 3)**
- xxxhDPI, 640dpi screen (ratio **4x**) --> bitmap: **192x192 px (48 x 4)**

In a nutshell, to answer your question, you have a different amount of **pixels** for different densities but the same number of **dps**.