# Creating a popup window with DP dimensions

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to create a popup window for my app that will be the same size as my buttons which are 300dp wide. However the constructor for the popup window takes float values.

```
mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            PopUpView,
            300,
            500
    );
```

Is there a way to create a popup window that will stick to dp dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to convert any `dp` value to it's current device pixel value use below Api for conversion.

```
val displayMetrics = context.resources.displayMetrics
val dpValue1 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300f, displayMetrics)
val dpValue2 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 500f, displayMetrics)

mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            PopUpView,
            dpValue1,
            dpValue2
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to obtain the size of your button in terms of pixels, using [getWidth()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth()) and [getHeight()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()), like so:

```
mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
    PopUpView,
    mButton.getWidth(),
    mButton.getHeight()
);
```

Be sure to call this after the layout has been inflated, or else `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` will return 0.

Another way is to take your desired value in dp and convert it to pixels yourself, then feed that into the `PopupWindow` constructor. Read more on this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp).