# PopupMenu does not show properly

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I am making an Android Application, and in some of the activities, I'm making the application show a PopupMenu when some items are clicked.

Problem is that the PopupMenu does not show all the options at once, instead, I'll have to scroll down the PopupMenu to see the rest of the menu options.

This problem happens in two activities, but in a third activity, it's showing as I want, although I'm using the same code to create the PopupMenu in all of those three activities!

**these two photos clarify the problem I'm having:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF9Xe.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UreJa.jpg)

**and this is a photo of the activity that shows the menu as expected:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsOwj.jpg)

this is the code of one of the two activities that has the problem:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;

import com.example.android.grad_qurantutor.data.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FavoritesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.general_list);

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        final ArrayList<Ayah> arr = dbHelper.getFavorites();

        if(arr.size() > 0) {
            final AyahAdapter itemsAdapter = new AyahAdapter(this, arr);

            final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    final Ayah a = arr.get(i);
                    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(FavoritesActivity.this, listView);
                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_favorites_options, popup.getMenu());
                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                // Respond to a click on the "Add to Favorites" menu option
                                case R.id.unfavorite:
                                    dbHelper.unfavorite(a.getId());
                                    ArrayList<Ayah> arr = dbHelper.getFavorites();
                                    itemsAdapter.clear();
                                    itemsAdapter.addAll(arr);
                                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    return true;

                                case R.id.go_to_surah:
                                    Surah surah = dbHelper.getSurah(a.getSurahId());
                                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(FavoritesActivity.this, AyahsActivity.class);
                                    myIntent.putExtra("surahObj", surah);
                                    myIntent.putExtra("ayahNum", a.getNumber());
                                    startActivity(myIntent);
                                    return true;

                                case R.id.share_ayah:
                                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

                                    String shareBody = a.getText();

                                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , shareBody);

                                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent , "Share Using"));
                                    return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    popup.show();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

**AND** this is the menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/unfavorite"
        android:title="Unfavorite" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/go_to_surah"
        android:title="Go to the Surah" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share_ayah"
        android:title="Share" />


</menu>
```

**AND** this is the xml layout for the activity:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF8E1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

---

and here are the codes for the activity that is showing the menu properly as expected:

the activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;

import com.example.android.grad_qurantutor.data.DatabaseHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    class Listener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        private ArrayList<Ayah> arr;
        private ListView listView;
        public Listener(ArrayList<Ayah> arr, ListView listView){
            this.arr = arr;
            this.listView = listView;
        }
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final Ayah a = arr.get(i);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(SearchActivity.this, listView);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_searched_ayahs_options, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        // Respond to a click on the "Add to Favorites" menu option
                        case R.id.add_favorite2:
                            dbHelper.addFavoriteAyah(a.getId());
                            return true;

                        case R.id.go_to_surah2:
                            Surah surah = dbHelper.getSurah(a.getSurahId());
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, AyahsActivity.class);
                            myIntent.putExtra("surahObj", surah);
                            myIntent.putExtra("ayahNum", a.getNumber());
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            return true;

                        case R.id.share_ayah:
                            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

                            String shareBody = a.getText();

                            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , shareBody);

                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent , "Share Using"));
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    }

    public void search(View view){
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

        ArrayList<Ayah> arr = dbHelper.search(editText.getText().toString().trim());

        if(arr.size() > 0) {
            AyahAdapter itemsAdapter = new AyahAdapter(this, arr);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_list);

            listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new Listener(arr, listView));
        }
    }
}
```

**AND** this is the menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_favorite2"
        android:title="Add to Favorites" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/go_to_surah2"
        android:title="Go to the Surah" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/share_ayah"
        android:title="Share" />


</menu>
```

**AND** this the the xml layout for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF8E1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:hint="search" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:onClick="search"
        android:text="Search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFF8E1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `popup.setHeight()` to set the desired height.

You may also want to use `popup.showAsDropdown()` to get more control over where the popup appears. For instance, I wanted mine to appear at a certain position relative to `enterPhoneNumberButton`:

```
int xOffset = popupWidthInDP > enterPhoneNumberButton.getWidth() ? 0 : enterPhoneNumberButton.getWidth() / 2 - dpToPx(popupWidthInDP / 2);
popup.showAsDropDown(enterPhoneNumberButton, xOffset, -enterPhoneNumberButton.getHeight() - dpToPx(popupHeightInDP));
```

Comment: There are no such methods!

Comment: Converting dp to px is a common Android task that I created a utility method for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp