# Why dimension in dp are not what is to be expected?

Tags: android, user-interface, pixel

So I set a block to a width of 367dp and on screen it is **65mm**

But according to the documentation 1dp = 1 pixel@160dpi

1 inch = 2.54cm
25.4mm / 160px = 0.15875mm

so 1dp pixel should be 0.15875mm and thus 367dp should be **58.261mm**

Is something wrong in my math?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution and the size of your screen? This will help you figure out the screen density.

Android use screen density buckets: mdpi, hdpi, x-hdpi, xx-hdpi...
The screen sizes of the devices do not fall exactly in one bucket, but I think the system finds the best bucket with the closest dpis.

[This is the official documentation for screen densities](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)
[This medium post can help you figure out how to work for screen densities](https://blog.prototypr.io/designing-for-multiple-screen-densities-on-android-5fba8afe7ead)

As a rule, of thumb, unless there is a strong requirement (showing an object at exact scale on a specific device model), you should try avoiding sticking to millimeters on your design and focus more on building responsive content that fits many screens.

If you **really** want to measure things:

- [find screen density](https://www.android-examples.com/find-get-screen-density-in-android-programmatically/)
- [find screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)
- [convert dp to px and px to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp?rq=1)
- You now have the size in px of the screen, the size in dp, you should be able to use a ruler on the screen.

Comment: Thank I'll look this up. our client sometimes checks with a ruler the app dimensions, it has to be the exact same dimension as what was specified (to the millimeter). this app is only targeted for a single device.