# How to create custom dimen files for same DPI bucket devices?

Tags: android, layout, dimensions, 2d-games

I am writing an Android game and I am testing it in two devices at the same time:

- **Huawei P10 Lite**: 5.2", 1920x1080, 424dpi, xhdpi.
- **Huawei P40 Pro**:
  6.58", 2640x1200, 441dpi, xhdpi.

These two devices are utterly different, as they **differ in screen size and resolution**, but NOT in dpi and dpi bucket; **both are xhdpi**.

That means regardless the dimen files I create (dimen-mdpi, dimen-hdpi...), any graphic element looks the same in both phones, which completely **breaks the layout and proportions in the small phone**.

I'm taking this as a reference for bucket classification:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well dpi is all about resolution, and not screen size. If you want to create resources for screen sizes, and not screen resolutions, you should use [smalest width qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseSWQuali).

### According to the docs:

> One DIP is one pixel on an
> approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen),
> providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi screen
> this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be .75; etc.

So if I understand correctly, you would convert from pixel to `dp` by: `pixelSize / dip / 160`. In this case the formula for your device width in dp is as follows: `deviceWidthInPixels / (deviceDip / 160)`.

- *P10 width in dp*: 1080 / (424 / 160) = 407.54
- *P40 width in dp*: 1200 / (441 / 160) = 435.37

Looks like other people also came to this [conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390420/5601663)

Comment: After is few hours trying I found out creating a custom ```dimens.xml``` file inside a folder named either ```values-sw362``` or ```values-sw363``` did the trick. However, I'm struggling to know where did the 362 come from.