# What unit should I use to set imageView width and height in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

```
 imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 130;
 imageView.getLayoutParams().width= 230;
```

Here 130 and 230 are DP or pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in pixels.  All lengths and widths outside of xml are in pixels.  You can convert DP to pixels by using [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)  if you want to specify the size in dp.